# AWS CLI for S3 - Errno 2 No such file or directory: u'

Tags: python, windows, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to extract a few hundred GB of data from an S3 bucket to a Windows 10 computer's external hard drive and the command I'm using (in a .bat file with AWSCLI-64bit installed) is:

```
aws s3 sync s3://aws-extraction/ F:\Bowral-PE\ --delete --region ap-southeast-2 > "%SyncLogFile%"
```

For the most part it seems to be working because files seem to be downloading and directories seem to be getting created.  So far there's 82GB of data downloaded, but every single line says in the cmd verbose output shows:

> download failed: s3://aws-extraction/Archive/somedirectory/ to
>   F:\Bowral-PE\Archive\somedirectory Errno 2 No such file or directory:
>   u'F:\Bowral-PE\Archive\somedirectory '

Any ideas why I'm getting this and how to stop it?

Please note that the AWSCLI seems to be using Python or something similar (a guess based on results when searching for the error), and I am a complete newbie when it comes to Python.

Comment: Could you please add what version of the AWS CLI you are using? (`aws --version`)

Comment: The `u` in `u'F:..` is fine, it is the way Python sometime prints unicode strings. What bothers me is the `Archive*somedirctory*` string with stars.  Are there on S3 some files on paths with stars in path names?

Comment: no Jan, there's not.  That was just me failing to italicise the quote properly.
`aws-cli/1.10.14 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.4.5`

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved @ReeceDodds? I'm having the same issue on Windows 10 `aws-cli/1.10.67 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.4.57`

Comment: No I didn't mate.  The downloads all completed though.  A strange one.  Best of luck with your issue

Answer (score 1):

I hit the similar problem when using the msi version of latest awscli on my windows 10 today:

```
C:>aws s3 sync s3://<my_bucket_name>/ <local_dir>
   fatal error [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The above sync command works if I backup the bucket content to a unix machine.

After some googling, seems the "fatal error [Errno 2] No such file or directory" is coming out from python.

I realised the awscli's windows msi version uses the self contained python (v2.7), which may be too old for windows 10.

I then installed the latest python (v3.6), used pip way to install awscli following the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html).

After this the direct backup / restoration works as expected.

Comment: yup s4 sync should work for directory syncs and resolve the above error you getting

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting this notification at the same time:

[image]

By clicking on it and allowing Python to access the folder I was trying to save it in, I was able to rerun the command and it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and after a lot of debugging, I enabled [Windows long paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry), and the issue went away.

Here's how I did it:

> The registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD) must exist and be set to 1. The key's value will be cached by the system (per process) after the first call to an affected Win32 file or directory function (see below for the list of functions). The registry key will not be reloaded during the lifetime of the process. In order for all apps on the system to recognize the value of the key, a reboot might be required because some processes may have started before the key was set.